# Spring JPA query with clause "where value in (select id from otherTable)"

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I want to write a JPA query that extracts all my entities matching a simple condition (column=boolean value) and a more complex conditions, i.e. the entity ID shall be contained in another table. MyEntity has no relationship with this other table.

My not working guess is:

```
@Query(value =
    "select msr " +
    "from MyEntity msr " +
    "where msr.archived=false " +
    " AND msr.id in 
        (select sc.res from search_campaign_results sc 
        where search_campaign_id=:campaign)")
Page<MyEntity> findResultsNotAnalyzed(Pageable pr, @Param("campaign") Long campaign);
```

Of course the error is "search_campaign_results is not mapped", which is correct .

How can I fix this without writing a completely native query?

Comment: Why it isn't sufficient, to write a native query in the form `@Query(value = "...", countQuery = "...", nativeQuery = true)` (see [Example 64 in "Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native))? Somehow, especially if a table of the sub-select has no entity representation, I don't think there is a simpler solution.

Comment: @hjoeren it is sufficient, but then I have to explicitly write the other table joins